# Rotating Standard Graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Is there are way to rotate standard graphs in tikz?

For example, the following produces a cyclic graph with 6 vertices

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill,circle,very thick,inner sep=0pt}]
  \graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is there a way I can rotate this graph by a given angle?

Answer (score 12):

Using `rotate` and `transform shape` you can rotate the graph any angle you choose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={fill,circle,very thick,inner sep=0pt}] 
\begin{scope}[rotate=15,transform shape]
\graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]}; 
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just for testing, the graph generated by library Graphs actues as a node, when you use scope with the modificator rotate, only afects coordinates, to rotate each node you must declare the rotate value in each node style; the correct way is using trasform shape, here a test of these aspects included basic tikz code drawing, in red, and imported images in nodes using graphicx.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE: animation using imagemagik converter

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: animate: {density: 150, delay: 15, other: -background white -alpha remove}
% arara: showanimate
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard,calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,29}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={
                fill=blue!20,
                circle,
                very thick,
                inner sep=0pt,
                minimum size=12pt
        }
    ] 
    \pgfmathparse{int(12*\x)}
    \edef\Angle{\pgfmathresult}
    %Set image limits to avoid flickering
    \draw(-3,4) rectangle (9,-9);
    \draw(90:2.7) node[fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {Scope{[}rotate=0{]}}
    ++(6,0) node[fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {Scope{[}rotate=\Angle{]}}
    ++(0,-6) node[fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {Scope{[}rotate=\Angle,trasform shape{]}}
    ++(-6,0) node[fill=none,font=\scriptsize] {Scope{[}rotate=0{]}, each node{[}rotate=\Angle{]}};
    %basic drawing test
    \begin{scope}[rotate=0] 
        %Graph generated objet
        \graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]};
        %Tikz basic code objet
        \foreach \n in {1,2,...,6}{
            \node[fill=red!20](n\n) at (60*\n:1.5){\n}; 
        }
        \draw[red,->](n1) 
        -- (n2) -- node[midway,sloped,above=-10pt, font=\tiny,fill=none]{tikz objet} (n3) -- (n4) 
        -- (n5) -- (n6) -- (n1);
        \node[label={-90:\tiny Angle}] at (0:2.5cm) {0};
        %Graphicx Objet
        \node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}};
        \node at (180:2.5cm){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};       
    \end{scope}

    %test rotate
    \begin{scope}[shift={(6,0)},rotate=\Angle]

    %Graph generated objet
    \graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]};
    %Tikz basic code objet
    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,6}{
        \node[fill=red!20](n\n) at (60*\n:1.5){\n}; 
    }
    \draw[red,->](n1) 
    -- (n2) -- node[midway,sloped,above=-10pt, font=\tiny,fill=none]{tikz objet} (n3) -- (n4) 
    -- (n5) -- (n6) -- (n1);
    \node[label={-90:\tiny Angle}] at (0:2.5cm) {\Angle};
    %Graphicx Objet
    \node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}};
    \node at (180:2.5cm){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};       
    \end{scope}

    %test rotate nodes
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6)},rotate=0]
    %Graph generated objet
    \graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]};
    %Tikz basic code objet
    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,6}{
        \node[fill=red!20,rotate=\Angle](n\n) at (60*\n:1.5){\n};   
    }
    \draw[red,->](n1) 
    -- (n2) -- node[midway,sloped,above=-10pt, font=\tiny,fill=none,rotate=\Angle]{tikz objet} (n3) -- (n4) 
    -- (n5) -- (n6) -- (n1);
    \node[label={-90:\tiny Angle},rotate=\Angle] at (0:2.5cm) {\Angle};
    %Graphicx Objet
    \node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,angle=\Angle]{example-image}};
    \node at (180:2.5cm){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm,angle=-\Angle]{example-image-a}};         
    \end{scope}

    %test 4 transform shape
    \begin{scope}[shift={(6,-6)},rotate=\Angle, transform shape]    
    %Graph generated objet
    \graph[clockwise, radius=2cm] {subgraph C_n [n=6]};
    %Tikz basic code objet
    \foreach \n in {1,2,...,6}{
        \node[fill=red!20](n\n) at (60*\n:1.5){\n}; 
    }
    \draw[red,->](n1) 
    -- (n2) -- node[midway,sloped,above=-10pt, font=\tiny,fill=none]{tikz objet} (n3) -- (n4) 
    -- (n5) -- (n6) -- (n1);
    \node[label={-90:\tiny Angle}] at (0:2.5cm) {\Angle};
    %Graphicx Objet
    \node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image}};
    \node at (180:2.5cm){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};       
    \end{scope}

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the [tkz-berge](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-berge) package. It is especially designed for graph theory and the rotation is easily set through the options.

```
\documentclass[11pt,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\GraphInit[vstyle=Shade]
\SetVertexNoLabel
\grCycle[x=0,y=0, rotation=90]{6}
\grCycle[x=10,y=0]{6}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output running in Gummi is:
[image]
Notice there is a command for cycles, \grCycle, and in the options the placement of the first cycle is put at x=0 and y=0 and is rotated 90 degrees. Also notice there are specific looks you can make your graph have; the one below is `Shade`. There is also the option to label vertices inside or outside and to weight the arcs.

**EDIT:** I should also point out the "Gallery of Named Graphs" which is [here](http://altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/NamedGraphs.pdf). This includes 3 different representations of the Petersen graph, cages, and others not mentioned in the documentation of tkz-berge.