# Rotating graph with tikz without rotating labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, rotating

I'm trying to rotate a drawing of K4 so that it forms a square instead of a diamond. I'm using the `scope` environment, but when I put `transform shape` as an option, I find the labels rotate as well. Removing the option, however, causes the shape to not rotate. I've included the latex code I wrote as well as the result after compilation. I saw an answer in [Rotating Standard Graphs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446225/rotating-standard-graphs) that seemed to do it correctly, but I couldn't reproduce it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, every node/.style={circle, draw}]
    \graph[clockwise, radius=3cm] {subgraph C_n [name=A,V={A,B,C,D}] };
    \begin{scope}[rotate=45, transform shape]
        \graph[clockwise, radius=1.25cm] {subgraph K_n [name=B,V={E,F,G,H}] };
    \end{scope}
    \node[draw=none, rectangle, above=0.8cm] at (current bounding box.north) {$L(G)$};

    \draw (A A) -- (B E);
    \draw (A A) -- (B F);

    \draw (A B) -- (B F);
    \draw (A B) -- (B G);

    \draw (A C) -- (B G);
    \draw (A C) -- (B H);

    \draw (A D) -- (B H);
    \draw (A D) -- (B E);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! You should not rotate the subgraph but change its `phase`. The default value of the `phase` is 90, you want to rotate by 45, so you need `135`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, every node/.style={circle, draw}]
    \graph[clockwise, radius=3cm] {subgraph C_n [name=A,V={A,B,C,D}] };
    \graph[clockwise, radius=1.25cm,phase=135] {
        subgraph K_n [name=B,V={E,F,G,H}] };
    \node[draw=none, rectangle, above=0.8cm] at (current bounding box.north) {$L(G)$};

    \draw (A A) -- (B E);
    \draw (A A) -- (B F);

    \draw (A B) -- (B F);
    \draw (A B) -- (B G);

    \draw (A C) -- (B G);
    \draw (A C) -- (B H);

    \draw (A D) -- (B H);
    \draw (A D) -- (B E);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW one can also simplify the construction of the edges quite a bit but this is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure I could do something with a for loop here, but since there aren't that many edges I just decided to manually write them.

Comment: @PolarBITS Yes, this was just an off-topic comment. I meant something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm, every node/.style={circle, draw}]
    \graph[clockwise] {subgraph C_n [radius=3cm,name=O,V={A,B,C,D}] 
 -- [matching] 
  subgraph C_n [,radius=0.25cm,name=I,V={E,F,G,H},phase=135] 
  };
    \node[draw=none, rectangle, above=0.8cm] at (current bounding box.north) {$L(G)$};
\end{tikzpicture}`.